# cs-cart admin user login always act as vendor profile Issue

Tags: cs-cart

I face one issue and not found any solution through cs-cart community That is - When I login to admin area from my admin URL like https://demo.com/admin.php and enter correct authentication infromation and click on login then I always act as Vendor not like admin it means that my after login screen is same as vendor screen and cant access any admin features.
After login my URL is same as admin URL but I act as vendor instead of admin. 
I double check my database user settings and all are correct also. My admin `user_type` is also 'A' and its enabled also.
I cant trace any issue from my server file side.
Is it is SSL issue?
Thanks for contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have any vendor selected already, on top left, right side of the admin logo, you should have All vendors ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for support but its not like that. There is not All vendor option as you mention. but i found my solution to set **company_id**  to 0 where user_type is A  in table **cscart_cs_users** . After login i can see actual admin panel dashboard look.